# custom range slider hidden in table view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I've created a custom range slider in an iOS project using this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/7595-how-to-make-a-custom-control-tutorial-a-reusable-slider

Using Xcode 10.1 and Swift 4.2.1.

The only difference is, I've removed the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` part because I've done it in the storyboard. Here I placed a UIView in the storyboard, set its contraints, set its class to `RangeSlider` and created an `@IBOutlet weak var rangeSlider: RangeSlider!` in the view controller.

I'm using a static table view but with a dynamic cell height:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0
}
```

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

If I change the font size the cells height gets adapted, which is what I want, but somehow the cell with the rangeSlider in it, covers one half of the rangeSlider. It doesn't matter if I play around with the font size, rotate the screen etc. It's always covered.

[image]

Can someone help? Am I missing something?

Comment: As there is no font in the `UITableViewlCell` it will not resize for the given font. The `automaticDimension` and the `.estimatedRowHeight` do not really 'force' a height. Besides, the height of the slider is very small, only a couple of pixels. It resizes 'correctly' as there is, according to the functions, not much height required to have the slider fit in the cell.

Comment: @Craz1k0ek I've logged the height from the rangeSlider (print statement in viewDidLoad). It says 30 points. The default slider one cell above has a height of 31 points. So what I don't understand, why is the upper cell extending itself so the slider fits in, but the other cell with the custom slider somehow don't want to extend its height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For automatic dimension to work, you must have an unbroken chain of constraints from the top of the `contentView` to the bottom and every item in that chain need to have an explicit height or an intrinsicContentSize.

From what I can tell from the tutorial they do not define an [intrinsicContentSize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622600-intrinsiccontentsize) for the custom slider.  UIKit gives controls that have an [intrinsicContentSize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622600-intrinsiccontentsize) a width and height constraint equal to their intrinsicContentSize if you don't otherwise constrain them.  So 1) implement `intrinsicContentSize` or 2) manually add a fixed height constraint **IN ADDTION TO** a top and bottom constraint to the tableViewCell's content view.

Comment: Ahhh yeah makes sense and of course it works, have used a size constraint on the UIView. The other "from top to bottom constraints" for that cell were already set. Was missing just this last height constraint. Thanks